# difference between working directory of docker and singularity

Tags: docker, singularity-container

I have a very basic question about docker and singularity. I'd like to be able to run a docker container using both docker and singularity, but I'm confused about the difference between the working directory. Here's an example: INSIDE my docker container, I have `main.sh` and `test.sh`.

Content of `main.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Executing main.sh"
./test.sh
```

Content of `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Executing test.sh"
```

When executing the following:
`sudo docker run -t myuser/mydocker:1.0 ./main.sh`

I get the expected output:

```
Executing main.sh
Executing test.sh
```

But when executing `singularity exec -e docker://myuser/mydocker:1.0 /main.sh`

I get this error:

```
Executing main.sh
/main.sh: line 4: ./test.sh: No such file or directory
```

Why is `test.sh` not accessible? Is there a way to let it work through singularity without changing the content of `main.sh`? My singularity version is 3.6.3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the big differences between docker and singularity.

In docker, the working directory is set in the `Dockerfile` with `WORKDIR /some/path` or the `-w /some/path` command line argument. Otherwise, it uses the default of `/`.

With singularity however, your home directory (or current directory, on older versions) on the host machine is mounted in and used as the working directory inside the container. You can use the `--pwd` flag to override this.

So given the Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY main.sh test.sh /
```

Running with docker:

```
$ docker run --rm myuser/mydocker:1.0 ./main.sh
Executing main.sh
Executing test.sh

$ docker run --rm myuser/mydocker:1.0 pwd
/
```

In singularity:

```
# note the full path of the file that isn't found
$ singularity exec -e mydocker.sif ./main.sh
FATAL:   stat /home/tsnowlan/main.sh: no such file or directory

# does NOT match the WORKDIR from the Dockerfile
$ singularity exec -e mydocker.sif pwd
/home/tsnowlan

# use full path to the script
# BUT still executing from $HOME so `./test.sh` is resolves to `$HOME/test.sh`
$ singularity exec -e mydocker.sif /main.sh
Executing main.sh
/main.sh: line 4: ./test.sh: No such file or directory

# tell singularity to run from /
$ singularity exec -e --pwd / mydocker.sif ./main.sh
Executing main.sh in
Executing test.sh
```

Comment: Can --pwd be used in conjunction with --bind? 
Eg: `singularity exec --bind /path/to/bind:/mnt --pwd /mnt ./main.sh`